# missing pdb file

Tags: .net, multithreading, debugging, windows-ce, pdb-files

I'm debugging my app on a wince7 device.

After couple minutes I'm getting an error: "No symbols are loaded for any call stack frame. The source code cannot be displayed."

I noticed on the modules list that I have 1 dll that is missing pdb file. Its name is System.Drawing.dll . 
I noticed that the module added to the module list after some thread (that I'm not creating and I don't know who) is created.

I'm getting the error only after the thread is running.

Anyone know where can I find the needed pdb file? (I have already tried to repair the .net compact framework)

How can I find out where the thread is starting? (I can't find it in the code)

What should I do next?

Please help

Comment: You have to enable .NET Framework source stepping in the Options dialog.

Answer (score 8):

Inside of visual studio

Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols ->  Check the Microsoft symbol server to be the location to get the symbols from.

Also in the General tab in Debugging uncheck the "Enable Just my Code" which will allow to debug into other assemblies.

Also enable the .NET Framework source stepping checkbox.

But what i would recommend is to download all symbols from the symbol server and save them locally.

Then add the local directory path as the symbol path in the Symbols in Visual Studio.

To download symbols ->

In the symbols tab in Debugging, check the Microsoft Symbol Server and press OK. Visual Studio will automatically download symbols to the Cache Directory

```
  C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Local\Temp\SymbolCache
```

After the download is complete you can add another path and point to this directory and uncheck Microsoft Symbol Server or move your local path above the Symbol Server path.

Now you should be able to load the symbols and get Method names.

You may also want to have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff558829(v=vs.85).aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I have found the symbol for System.Drawing.dll. Now it asks for symbol for mscorlib . Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: If you have followed the steps you can look into the local cache directory of your Visual Studio under the debugging tab in Tools -> Options, open the directory and check for a folder named mscorlib. If it's not there, then check the Microsoft Symbol Server checkbox and your application will download the symbols when running. I think that will do it for you.

Comment: I can't find the Microsoft Symbol Server checkbox. where can i find it? the visual studio downloaded the symbols but didn't downloaded this one.

Comment: I found this post http://goo.gl/4szP7 that shows how to set up the symbol server support. Please read it carefully and follow the procedure described. Hope it helps...:)

Comment: this is helps. I have found that I have the wrong dll. I have version 1.0.4292.00 and i need version 2 (mscorlib). I have tried to install .net 3.5 and I can't install it (nothing happens).
Maybe you know what should I do?

Comment: I have noticed that the dll is taken from the wrong place, from smart devices and not from .net compact framework. do you know why? how can i change it?

Comment: I am Sorry! I am not familiar with Compact framework but Yes this seems to be an issue with Compact Framework, have a look at this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/87461521-60d7-4785-8b01-1901d44caba1